# Static and dynamic routing related query

Tags: routing, network-core

Two different paths to the same network are present in the routing table: one entered statically: and the other learned through dynamic routing protocol. When forwarding a packet to that network, which route will the router choose, the static route or the dynamic route? I have one more confusion. if the router doesn't find a path to the destination in the routing table, will it forward the packet through all the interfaces?

Comment: You aren't supposed to change the question to ask new questions. For new questions you need to start a new question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both prefixes are equally long, it will choose the one with the lowest administrative distance. That would, by default, be the static route, but either one could have had the AD changed. For example, when you configure a static route, you can configure it with am AD higher than the learned prefix so that it is a floating static route.